# How i can register a company on the Apple Developer Site?

Tags: ios, app-store

i want to publish an app on the apple store and i want, that my company name was printed under the App Name? Where i can change this? Apple ask me only for my Name.

Comment: I would simply place it in the "copy right" section.

Comment: Where i can find the "copy right" section? I develop it with Xamarin, or can i find it, if i uploaded to the store? Thank you!

Comment: Once you get in the store you would need to fill out some information, and you would see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have uploaded your App, you would need to fill out some information. There you will need to fill out "Copy Right" section, where you could place your company name among with other legal notice you would like to display.